# Gnuplot from C program - Only allows for plotting for files over certain lengths

Tags: c, pipe, gnuplot

I think I have run into the weirdest bug I have ever encountered. I am using pipes in C for using gnuplot. I have a datafile named `corr.dat` which looks like this:

```
0 2.535107 2.535107
1 3.363503 3.363503
...
...
24 1.435642 0.821686
```

This file was generated through

```
for (i=0; i<25; i++) {
        fprintf(data_file, "%d %lf %lf\n", i, rv[i], fv[i])
}
```

where `rv` and `fv` are arrays of doubles. I can plot this through

```
FILE * gnuplot_pipe = popen("gnuplot -persistent", "w");
fprintf(gnuplot_pipe, "plot 'corr.dat'\n");
fflush(gnuplot_pipe);
```

which works just fine. But when I change the loop to

```
for (i=0; i<24; i++) {
```

I get an error from gnuplot saying

```
line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

gnuplot> plot 'corr.dat'
                        ^
line 0: x range is invalid
```

The pattern persists - for numbers 25 and over gnuplot happily plots, but calls everything invalid when below. What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you didn't close `data_file` before calling gnuplot, so if you print just a small quantity of data is isn't actually flushed to disk.

Make sure to call `fclose(data_file)` before your `popen`.

Comment: Yes this was it! Thanks!